# Content from the same content type as the current user

Tags: views

I have users with a "field_org" entity reference (multiple values allowed) to the "Org" content type. I also have a "field_org" (single value) in my "Article" content type.

When looking at a user profile (let's call this user "UserA"), how do I build a view that gets you "articles from your orgs" (i.e. created by other users that also belong to any of UserA's orgs)? And, bonus question: how do I exclude articles created by UserA? (since I have a separate "your articles" view showing in the same page).

I know this is probably a combination of relationships and contextual filters, but I can't figure out exactly how to configure them. Probably something like this:

- Contextual filter on node author to prevent "UserA's articles" from showing (set to "exclude" in the options)
- Contextual filter on node author, but probably set to one of the relationships below.
- Relationship between article nodes and orgs?
- Relationship between orgs and users?

Both contextual filters would load the same user ID using "Provide default value".

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a content view
2. Add the `Content: Author` relationship
3. Add the `Content: Author uid` contenxtual filter

   - Provide default value: `User ID from URL`

So far we have a view displaying content created by a certain user, we still have to narrow down the results to a single content type.

4. Add the `Content: Type filter = Org`

Note that a `page` view (with a path) will show no results if you just hit the path. To have results you must pass a `uid` to the url, like `mypath/%uid`. On the other hand you can create a block or a content pane and place/embedded it to the user's profile, view's will return all results (if any) for you!